# Flask HTML page will not render even with simple route/method

Tags: python, flask

I am in a class trying to create a simple Python Flask login/register web page. I was able to successfully create the login page, but no matter what I do, the register page won't render at all. I even removed everything from the register method asking it to just return the render_template. Still nothing. Please help me figure this out. Also, I'm sure there are plenty of things that I could do better or change to make improvements, for now, I just need to get this done because I'm behind.

my .py app.routes

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('login.html',utc_dt=datetime.datetime.utcnow ())

@app.route('/register',methods=["GET","POST"])
def register():
    return render_template('register.html')
```

my register.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!--This tag links this file to the CSS file in the static folder -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href='static/loginstyle.css' />
        <!--This title is displayed on the page tab instead of the top of the page -->
        <title>Register Credentials</title>
    </head>
    <body class="login_body">
        <p>{{msg}}</p>
        </br>
        </br>
        <h1>Input a new username and password</h1>
        <form action="{{url_for('register')}}" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
            <div class="login_form">
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder={{username_ph}}>
            </div>
            <div class="login_form">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder={{pwd_ph}}>
            </div>
            <div class="login_form">
                <label for="password2">Re-enter password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password2" placeholder={{pwd2_ph}}>
            </div>
            <div class="login_form">
                <input type="submit" class="ok_click" value="Log In">
            </div>
        </form>
        <button onclick="href='{{url_for('login')}}';"
        class="button_click">
        Return to login
        </button>
        </br></br>
        <p class="pw_reqs">
        Create your password. It should have the following parameters:</br>
                12 characters long but no more than 18 with no spaces</br>
                At least one uppercase letter</br>
                At least one lowercase letter</br>
                At least one digit</br>
                Contains one of the following symbols:  * ! @ # $ ( )</br>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I just need to know what I need to do to make the register page render.

Comment: maybe `app.run()` ?

Comment: Are you sure it's in the right location? Like I think by default it should be /templates/register.html?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If this is the complete code you wrote, you need to add this at the beginning:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import datetime
```

and this at the end:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

If this code is then executed, an error has occurred:

```
File "c:\...\templates\register.html", line 30, in top-level template code <button onclick="href='{{url_for('login')}}';"
```

If you delete that line of html, the code will run.

I don't want to judge you, but did you debug or google the problem before posting it here?

Also You can add an page `def login` its importent that the def name and the name in url_for is the same
Example:

```
@app.route('/lg',methods=["GET","POST"])
def login():
    return {"test": "yay"}
```

Comment: I'm not gonna lie, I'm still not quite sure how to debug. One of the few things I haven't pursued figuring out. Either python has told me what was wrong with my code or I used pylint to make it better.  Ive been using python editor and notepad+ and im not sure how to debug. As for googling, yes, hours. I've  seen the name, main, app.run but I don't understand the point of it. Oh, and that isn't the entirety of my code so I do have the imports

Comment: Also, to clarify, that line of code has changed multiple times trying to figure out how to make it work. Mainly because the same button on login page code, which is similar, won't switch to the page I'm trying to figure out. At one point, I had both pages set up a certain way that going to local/login would work, but local/register wouldn't even though both codes are setup almost the same. Its maddening.

Comment: `if __name__ == '__main__':`
This says that it only runs when the Programm is executed as the main program and not when it is imported.

`app.run()` tells the class app to execute the function run.
In Flask means that to run the web Server.

To debug you can use code editors like "Visual Studio Code" (my favorite)
Here you can go line by line to debug and find errors.

`File "c:\...\templates\register.html", line 30, in top..."`
The First part says in witch file the error is the second in which line and the last what is wrong.

You can Ask again if there is something unclear :)

Comment: I appreciate it. Gotta head to work for now, but I'll edit your suggested lines. Im sure ill have more questions, but for now, thanks!

Comment: I've added the original post so there is an alternative solution instead of deleting it.
I think the def name is different or the login wasn't or isn't in the code.

Comment: So, officially, I'm not sure exactly what fixed it. I decided to move the register page to the index and now everything works as advertised.. I wanted the login page to be the first viewed page, but I'm not upset about it. However, I know there were issues with my register page which was fixed by your suggestions, so I'm gonna mark your answer as solved!